# Good tool to capture user activity logs

Tags: mysql, logging, android-activity, text

Right now in our site we are logging all user activities (logins, clicks etc.,) in MySQL or text files.

On both cases the IO operation increases, as a result site performance got degraded.

We need the user activity logs to be captured at any cost, is there any other better way we can capture the logs without affecting the site performance?

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions.

First, the web servers (Apache httpd, for example) capture their own logs, in flat text files, for every request. You can use the standard [Common Log Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Log_Format) or you can customize it. There's an extensive ecosystem of processing software for these logs. If you use these logs you can remove logging from your application code entirely. You'll still have the logs. That, I believe, is the best-performing solution. But processing the logs can be a pain in the neck.

Second, you said you're logging into both MySQL and text files. How about logging only into one or the other?

Third, MySQL offers the [`ARCHIVE` access method](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/archive-storage-engine.html) for tables. It is very cheap to write and takes a small amount of disk space. If you use MySQL to doyour logging you should consider this access method. Its disadvantage is that it cannot be indexed.  That is, MySQL needs to scan the whole table to satisfy queries with `WHERE` clauses in them.

Comment: Dear Ollie Jones, Thanks for your suggestions, definitely I will check on that. MySQL & Text - We are not storing simultaneously we tried with both. I will edit my question.